# Using a variable to set an object array in java

Tags: java, arrays, object

When I set an object array such as:

```
Player[] player = new Player[amountOfPlayers];
```

I use:

```
amountOfPlayers = br.read();
```

To get the variable `amountOfPlayers`. Whenever I run my program I would type in 3 when asked to set the `amountOfPlayers` but my output says there are 51 players.

Though when I set the new `Player` array to: `new Player[3]`; it works.

Anyone know why this would be?

Comment: Can you post the actual full code, as it is hard to guess what is going on here?

Comment: can you explain this? what is player here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you read a `char` and interpret it as an integer. The character `3` has ASCII code `51`.

It is probably easier to use a `Scanner` than a `BufferedReader` to read the input, as suggested by [Prasad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18100653/2095090).

Comment: thanks for mentioning :) upvote for the word ASCII which I forgot to mention.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to read input instead of `BufferedReader`
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    amountOfPlayers = in.nextInt();

This could be because `br.read()` reads the character value whichis `51` for `3`.

using `in.nextInt()` will ensure it is converted into int.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine());
```